# Which torrent client has preview mode?

Tags: bittorrent, client

On windows I used BitComet torrent client which has great feature - download files in preview mode so I can see movies right away.

uTorrent declared to be able to download files in preview mode but in real it doesn't.

Which torrent client has real preview mode?

Comment: @Prasad - Transmission does not have the feature requested, it cannot stream video.

Comment: The answer works easy, currently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### [qBittorrent](http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/)

qBittorrent developers claim to be producing a "free" alternative to uTorrent.

One of their features is *Sequential downloading (aka "Download in order")*

However, this feature is with a [health warning](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/qbittorrent/index.php?title=QBittorrent_2_English_documentation):

> Attempts to download the selected torrents in sequential order.
>   Torrent pieces are usually downloaded in an optimal order which
>   maximizes speed and benefits to the swarm health. Downloading in
>   sequential order is useful for preview files. However, this feature is
>   against Bittorrent protocol recommendations due to its negative effect
>   on the swarm. It is thus discouraged to use this feature. A more
>   detailed explanation of why this feature is bad is available [here](http://azureuswiki.com/index.php/Sequential_downloading_is_bad)

Comment: I read the warning and am inclined to call bullshit on it. There is no backing experimental data proving their claim. On top of that, I refute their logic. When a swarm is downloading sequentially, the first pieces of a video have the highest demand. Therefore it makes sense and it's useful for the piece distribution to be skewed toward the video's beginning. This will be a problem if for some reason a user wants to download the very end of a video in a stream where only the beginning is widely available. So? I doubt sequential downloading would even present a problem in small swarms.

Answer (score 9):

- First install **qBittorrent** from the software center.
- Download the torrent using qBittorrent and right click and select "Download in sequential order".

[image]

- Wait for a while and then click preview file.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install qbittorrent' in your terminal works also.

Answer (score 1):

Utorrent is actually ok to view preview if setting are set correct. But like bakytn said kTorrent has this feature, but you have to look at the files you download to be sure if it works.(Like an .avi file should be no problem) But i dont know when it comes to .rar files that are splittet up e.g.

Try kTorrent.. or qTorrent maybe also i think..

And if it is sequential downloading you can turn that on or off or set the priority higher on some files e.g in the most torrent clients that i have used..

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

last versions of kTorrent 100% support preview. However it requries KDE libs