# How do I stream a video torrent?

Tags: software-recommendation, bittorrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which torrent client has preview mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61683/which-torrent-client-has-preview-mode)

Is there a software/s to stream a video torrent like [utorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/utorrent-plus/index/) on windows?